# Count frequency of words and return list of lists in java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to count the frequency of words in a sentence.

The sentence is:

"hey hi hey"`

The output should be:

```
List[List["hey",2],List["hi",1]]`
```

Comment: what did you try so far

Comment: are you sure you want a `List<List>`? May be a `Map<String, Integer>` instead?

Comment: `List["Hey",2]` is probably not what you want, Lists must be uniform on type of its elements (and I doubt you know which will be that type). Your result would be better captured in a map of word/count (`Map<String,Integer>`).

Answer (score 1):

In case you change your mind to want a `Map<String, Integer>`, here is a way (since `List<List<Object>>` makes little sense anyway)

```
 youList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             Function.identity(),
             Collectors.counting()
 ))
```

You can replace `Collectors.counting()` with `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)` for a small improvement under java-8.

Comment: for completeness:  `Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream("hey hi hey")` instead of `youList.stream()`

Comment: @Lino if Op would have said "I have a String..." (vs I have a `List`) would have agreed...

Comment: @Lino nvm that was edited apparently :) it was I  have a list